# O que significa o seletor CSS :first-child e :last-child?

Tags: jquery, css, css3, seletores

Tenho um código usando jQuery que se baseava nos seletores CSS `:first-child` e
`:last-child` (e que funcionou por um bom tempo), para obter o primeiro `input`
e o último `input` dentro de um grupo contendo *input + select + input*...
O primeiro `input` era o valor inicial de um intervalo,
e o último era o valor final do dito intervalo,
sendo que no meio está o `select` com operadores de exclusão/inclusão
das extremidades.

Estava assim:

```
var $inputIni = $("input:first-child", controlDiv),
    $inputFim = $("input:last-child", controlDiv),
    $select = $("select", controlDiv);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kpgf/1/)

Cheguei à conclusão de que os inputs não tinham o propósito claro para
o usuário final, e resolvi colocar labels para os mesmos, assim como para o
select do meio. A partir daí o seletor `:first-child` não funcionou mais.
Não consigo mais chegar até os elemento usando o seletor... porque isso?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kpgf/2/)

Imagino que o mesmo problema, seja qual for, possa também um dia acontecer com
o seletor `:last-child`, então como entender o problema?

Answer (score 18):

### Pseudo-classes não funcionam assim

É comum fazer esta confusão sobre o significado dos seletores `:first-child`
e `:last-child`, também chamados de pseudo-classes, além de outras pseudo-classes
que denotam posição.

As pseudo-classes, quando usadas em um seletor, não levam em conta o restante
do seletor em questão, portanto o seletor `input:first-child` **não se refere ao
primeiro input**, mas sim ao **input que seja o primeiro filho de seu pai**.

Isso quer dizer que a pseudo-classe `:first-child` irá marcar qualquer que seja
o **primeiro elemento que seja filho de um outro qualquer**. O mesmo
ocorre com a pseudo-classe `:last-child` que irá marcar somente o último filho.

Analogamente, `input:last-child` significa: **o input que é o último filho**.
Outras pseudo-classes de posição também funcionam de forma análoga.
Vejamos uma lista com os respectivos significados:

- [`input:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child): input que seja coincidentemente o primeiro filho do pai
- [`input:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child): input que seja coincidentemente o último filho do pai
- [`input:nth-child(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child): input que seja coincidentemente o segundo filho do pai
- [`input:nth-last-child(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child): input que seja coincidentemente o penúltimo filho do pai
- [`input:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type): input que seja coincidentemente o primeiro do tipo no pai
- [`input:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type): input que seja coincidentemente o último do tipo no pai
- [`input:nth-of-type(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type): input que seja coincidentemente o segundo do tipo no pai
- [`input:nth-last-of-type(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type): input que seja coincidentemente o penúltimo do tipo no pai
- [`input:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child): input que seja coincidentemente o primeiro e último filho do pai (equivale a `input:first-child:last-child`)
- [`input:only-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type): input que seja coincidentemente o primeiro e último filho do tipo no pai (equivale a `input:first-of-type:last-of-type`)

### Soluções para o problema

Existem algumas soluções para o problema apresentado:

- Usar IDs para os inputs especificos ao invés do que está sendo feito, talvez
  concatenando com o ID da div que agrupa os elementos, como indicado no
  jsfiddle, assim: `<input name="ctl_ini" id="ctl_ini" />` e o seletor assim:
  `$("#ctl_ini")`
- Usar as pseudo-classes `:first-of-type` e `:last-of-type` assim:
  `$("#ctl input:first-of-type")` e `$("#ctl input:last-of-type")`

  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cr7C8/)

  Note que para uso em CSS, o suporte é um pouco limitado. Mas no jQuery pode
  usar sem preocupação.

### Uma nova confusão com o `:first-of-type`

As pseudo-classes `:first-of-type` e outras que se baseiam no tipo do
elemento, voltam a causar uma certa confusão, pois
aparentemente no seletor `input:first-of-type` a pseudo-classe está
se baseando no restante do seletor para obter o resultado, o que não é verdade.

Exemplo:

- `a.cls:first-of-type`: elemento do tipo `a`, com a classe CSS `cls` que é coincidentemente o primeiro do tipo.

  Como estamos selecionando o tipo do elemento: `a`, então os únicos "primeiros do tipo" serão coincidentemente do tipo `a`,
  mas isso não quer dizer que a pseudo-classe `:first-of-type` se baseou no que veio antes no seletor. Tanto é verdade
  que ela ignora a classe do seletor: `cls` em sua decisão, ou seja, esse seletor **não significa** *o primeiro `a` com a classe `cls`*.

### Solução mantendo `:first-child` e `:last-child`

Como antes você selecionava os `input`s que eram primeiro e último filhos de seu pai e agora colocou-os dentro de `label`s, tenha em mente que agora as `label`s estão no exato mesmo lugar onde os `input`s estavam, logo elas são `label:first-child`/`select`/`label:last-child`. Tendo isso em mente podemos resolver a situação simplesmente mudando um pouco os seletores:

```js
var fncDoSomethingWithCtl = function ($ctl) {
    
    var $inputIni = $("label:first-child input", $ctl),
        $inputFim = $("label:last-child input", $ctl),
        $select = $("select", $ctl);
    
    $inputIni.css({"border-color": "#C1E0FF", 
                   "border-width":"4px", 
                   "border-style":"solid"});
    
    $inputFim.css({"border-color": "#E0C1FF", 
                   "border-width":"4px", 
                   "border-style":"solid"});
    
    $select.css({"border-color": "#C1FFE0", 
                 "border-width":"4px", 
                 "border-style":"solid"});
    
}

$(function () {
    
    var $ctlDiv = $("#ctl");
    fncDoSomethingWithCtl($ctlDiv);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctl">
    <label>
        <span>Início:</span>
        <input type="text"/>
    </label>
    <select>
        <option>inc até inc</option>
        <option>exc até inc</option>
        <option>inc até exc</option>
        <option>exc até exc</option>
    </select>
    <label>
        <span>Fim:</span>
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
</div>
```

### Conclusão

A conclusão, é uma medida de segurança para o desenvolvedor:

pseudo-classes devem ser tratadas **sempre** como meras coincidências...
para saber o que a pseudo-classe realmente significa,
basta usá-la sem mais nada no mesmo seletor
e então fazer um AND assim:

- `a:first-child` vai selecionar os elementos forem selecionados tanto pelo
  seletor `a` como pelo seletor `:first-child`

Então basta testar ambos os seletores separadamente,
e depois mesclar os resultados e prestar muita atenção nos níveis de cada elemento dentro de um documento, como nesse caso, a `label` ocupou o lugar do `input` e o tornou seu filho, onde o `input` caiu na hierarquia do arquivo e virou `:last-child` de uma `label` onde o `:first-child` era um `span`.

### Referência:

[Informações sobre as pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Comment: Excelente esclarecimento. Também descobri isso não há muito tempo atrás quando estava implementando um [seletor CSS em java](https://github.com/utluiz/jericho-selector/) baseado na especificação do W3C. Na minha opinião esses seletores são pouco intuitivos se você não ler a documentação com muita atenção.