# Dúvida com seletor CSS

Tags: css, css3

Pessoal tou fazendo um grid que exibe de 1 a n imagens sendo que em cada linha ele mostra 2 colunas. A estrutura HTML é esta:

```
<div id="container">
    <h2 class="linhasFotos">
        <a title="nome da linha" href="/lancamentos">
            <img src="../../public/images/foto-01.jpg" width="470" height="236" class="img-zoom"
                 alt="nome da linha"/>
        </a>
    </h2><!--Toda página deve conter pelo menos 1 (uma) tag h2-->

    <h2 class="linhasFotos">
        <a title="nome da linha" href="/lancamentos">
            <img src="../../public/images/foto-01.jpg" width="470" height="236" class="img-zoom"
                 alt="nome da linha"/>
        </a>
    </h2>
    <h2 class="linhasFotos">
        <a title="nome da linha" href="/lancamentos"><
            <img src="../../public/images/foto-01.jpg" width="470" height="236" class="img-zoom"
                 alt="nome da linha"/>
        </a>
    </h2><
</div>
```

O CSS é este da classelinhaFotos:

```
.linhasFotos {
float:left;
margin-right: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 470px;
height: 236px
}
```

A minha dúvida é como criar o seletor que vai colocar o margin-right=0 toda vez que elemento for o ultimo objeto da linha.
Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer uso do seletor [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) para remover a margem a cada X elementos consoante a tua necessidade:

```
/* A cada 2 elementos, retira a margem */
.linhasFotos:nth-child(2n+2){
  margin-right:0;
}
```

Podes utilizar este [teste do seletor `:nth`](https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/) criado pelo pessoal do CSS-Tricks.

### Exemplo

```css
li:nth-child(2n+2){
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1º</li>
  <li>2º</li>
  <li>3º</li>
  <li>4º</li>
  <li>5º</li>
  <li>6º</li>
  <li>7º</li>
  <li>8º</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Deu certinho. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Se você quiser garantir que está selecionando somente os elementos `h2`, de 2 em 2, é possível utilizar o seletor [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type). Assim sendo podemos misturar outros elementos juntamente com os `h2`, e ainda assim selecioná-los de 2 em 2.

Todos os browsers modernos [suportam este seletor](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), mas o IE8 e outros mais antiquados terão problemas. Também tem uma tabela de compatibilidade ao [final da página da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

[Em uma outra resposta, eu explico detalhadamente os seletores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9184/1925):
`:first-child`,
`:last-child`,
`:nth-child`,
`:nth-last-child`,
`:first-of-type`,
`:last-of-type`,
`:nth-of-type`,
`:nth-last-of-type`

No exemplo abaixo, adicionei uma DIV antes dos H2. Mas poderiam ser 2 DIVs ou nenhuma DIV, que não faria diferença... funcionaria em qualquer caso.

```css
.linhasFotos {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
h2.linhasFotos:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
h2.linhasFotos:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Esse div não influencia no CSS, pois usa-se `nth-of-type`</div>
  <h2 class="linhasFotos">
        <a title="nome da linha" href="/lancamentos">
            <img src="../../public/images/foto-01.jpg" width="200" height="100" class="img-zoom"
                 alt="nome da linha"/>
        </a>
    </h2>
  <!--Toda página deve conter pelo menos 1 (uma) tag h2-->

  <h2 class="linhasFotos">
        <a title="nome da linha" href="/lancamentos">
            <img src="../../public/images/foto-01.jpg" width="200" height="100" class="img-zoom"
                 alt="nome da linha"/>
        </a>
    </h2>
  <h2 class="linhasFotos">
        <a title="nome da linha" href="/lancamentos">
            <img src="../../public/images/foto-01.jpg" width="200" height="100" class="img-zoom"
                 alt="nome da linha"/>
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Tamb[em funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o seletor [:last-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)

```
.linhasFotos a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: olha eu tinha tentado este método, mas ele só funciona no último elemento é não no último elemento da linha. Exemplo se eu tiver 3 elementos será aplicado no terceiro e não no segundo elemento da linha que é o último que eu desejo.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer colocar o `margin-right` para o último elemento da linha, mas, na estrutura do seu HTML, não existe uma linha definida. Para tal, recomendo a criação de um container para cada duas fotos, da seguinte maneira:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="container-imagens>"
        <h2 class="linhasFotos">
            <a title="nome da linha" href="/lancamentos">
                <img src="../../public/images/foto-01.jpg" class="img-zoom" alt=""/>
            </a>
        </h2><!--Toda página deve conter pelo menos 1 (uma) tag h2-->

        <h2 class="linhasFotos">
            <a title="nome da linha" href="/lancamentos">
                <img src="../../public/images/foto-01.jpg" class="img-zoom" alt=""/>
            </a>
        </h2>
    </div> <!-- end of .container-imagens -->    

    <div class="container-imagens">
        .
        .
        .
    </div> <!-- end of .container-imagens -->
</div> <!-- end of #container -->
```

Dessa maneira, você tem mais controle sobre cada 'linha' de imagens, além de que agora você pode usar o seletor `:last-of-type` para adicionar o `margin-right: 0`, que era a sua pergunta. o seu CSS então ficaria:

```
.container-imagens > .linhasFotos:last-of-type{margin-right: 0}
```

Vale lembrar que este seletor só vai funcionar se, no seu HTML, os elementos `.linhaFotos` sejam filhos diretos de elementos `.container-imagens`. Você pode ler mais sobre os seletores [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

A vantagem de trabalhar com o `:last-of-type` é que se amanhã, por qualquer motivo, você decidir que seu grid vai conter três imagens - ao invés de duas - em cada linha, você garante que apenas o último elemento (i.e., o mais à *direita*), vai herdar as propriedades do seletor. Usando os seletores como o `:nth-child` lhe prendem a matemática de uma maneira que pode ser difícil escapar depois. Eu criei uma Pen como prova de conceito, e você pode vê-la [aqui](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/MYxROo).

Aproveito para recomendar 3 coisas:

1. Evite qualquer regra de estilo inline, como `width` e `height` como atributos da tag `<img>`. É muito mais fácil (e prudente) controlar tais regras em um arquivo .css em separado.
2. Apesar do HTML 5 ser uma entidade mágica e agora permitir esse tipo de coisa (i.e., vai funcionar), colocar qualquer coisa além de texto dentro de uma tag `<h2>` não é uma boa prática, uma vez que esta tag é uma tag de **texto**. No seu caso, não vejo razão que justifique o uso do `<h2>`, mas cada um é cada um. =)
3. O CSS permite que você cascateie as regras de estilo, portanto, você pode enxugar o seu HTML para que ele fique mais simples. No seu caso, o seu seletor tornar-se-ia 
   `.container-imagens > h2:last-of-type{margin-right: 0}`
   , o que é muito mais fácil de ler e entender que "O último h2, filho do .container-imagens, não vai ter margem".

Espero ter ajudado! =)

EDIT: O terceiro container da prova de conceito mostra o HTML mais enxuto, como sugeri no item 3.