# Qual é a diferença entre :first-child e :first-of-type no CSS?

Tags: html, css, front-end

Eu estava escrevendo uma linha de código e já estava pronto para digitar `:first-of-type` para alterar um certo elemento. Foi então que me surgiu a dúvida: eu devo usar `first-of-type` ou `first-child`? Já que ambos apresentam o mesmo resultado!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9183/70

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que significa o seletor CSS :first-child e :last-child?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9183/o-que-significa-o-seletor-css-first-child-e-last-child)

Answer (score 3):

Veja o que diz a documentação oficial da **W3C** 
https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/

**:first-child** (primeiro filho)

> Same as `:nth-child(1)`. The `:first-child` pseudo-class represents an element that is first in a list of siblings.

Tradução:
*O mesmo que: `:nth-child(1)`. A pseudo-classe: `first-child` representa um elemento que é o primeiro de uma lista de irmãos.*

---

**:first-of-type** (primeiro irmão)

> Same as `:nth-of-type(1)`. The `:first-of-typ`e pseudo-class represents an element that is the first sibling of its type.

Tradução:
*O mesmo que `:nth-of-type(1)`. A pseudo-classe `first-of-type` representa um elemento que é o primeiro irmão de seu tipo.*

---

O valor de prioridade e hierarquia para os dois é a mesma, então se os dois estiverem presentes ao mesmo tempo o que vier por último vai sobrescrever o estilo do primeiro.

Veja esse teste com as classes, **aparentemente não á diferença de prioridade nas classes, e resumidamente o primeiro filho e o primeiro irmão tem o mesmo peso e o mesmo `index`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima

```css
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}
p:first-of-type {
    color: red;
}

p:first-child {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
    <h3>h3 aqui</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
        <h3>h3 aqui</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelos exemplos e pela explicação! :)

Comment: @HiGustavo  que bom que ajudou ai! Se vc acredita que essa resposta resolveu o seu problema considere marca-la como aceita nesse ícone ✔. Assim ela não fica pendente no site como pergunta não resolvida. Vc pode remover esse voto a qualquer momento caso queira, ou coloca-lo em outra resposta que surja e vc ache que te atende melhor. []´s